# How do I update OpenSSL on Windows 10 from 1.1.1h to 1.1.1o

Tags: windows, openssl

I have been researching how to update OpenSSL on windows 10 and can't seem to find a clear answer. I currently have 1.1.1h and am looking to upgrade to 1.1.1o because of CVE-2021-3711. If anyone knows of a guide somewhere or knows the procedure in general I can't find it.

How do I go about this update?

Comment: Since we're talking about Windows, I think each application that uses OpenSSL probably comes with its own copy, which could be in a DLL file or directly linked into an EXE.  Which specific applications are you concerned about?  How do you know you have 1.1.1h and how did you install that?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: historically _native_ Windows apps did that, but Win10 up has WSL where the library handling and update methods are the same as a selected Unix distro, and all versions of Win (at least NT up) have had other Unix-like schemes such as gnuwin32 and cygwin/mingw/mingw64 each with their own library scheme. But yes it depends on what you installed/use.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Unfortunately I can't be sure what was used to install it in the first place as that was before I was there. I can be sure it's 1.1.1h as I ran "openssl version" in PowerShell and it returned the version. I am just generally concerned about having that version on the remote desktop because of the vulnerability. I'm assuming there is no generally easy way to update the version without removing it and installing the version I want.

Comment: OK.  I don't have an `openssl` command in PowerShell on my machine so it must have been something that got installed later, instead of coming with Windows.  You could run `Get-Command openssl` to see where that command comes from.